Sending a comment by mail in youtrack - including attachements (images, zip etc.)
In Youtrack Helpdesk we had written a small workflow for sending Comments by Email. All works fine, only the images are not correct:
var entities = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/entities');
var notification = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/notifications');

  const resolveLinks = function (text) {
    var baseUrl = 'https://test.com/images/';
    
    var updatedText = text.replace(/!\[([^\]]*)\]\(([^)]+)\)/g, function(match, altText, url) {
        // Check if the URL is already absolute
        if (url.startsWith('http://') || url.startsWith('https://')) {
          return match;
        }
        // Replace with absolute URL
        return `![${altText}](${baseUrl}${url})`;
      });

      if (text !== updatedText) {
        text = updatedText;
      }
    
    return text;
  };


exports.rule = entities.Issue.onChange({
  title: 'Send Email Notification',
  guard: function(ctx) {
    return true;
  },
  action: function(ctx) {
    var issue = ctx.issue;
    if (issue.comments.added.isNotEmpty()) {
      var authorName = issue.comments.added.first().author.fullName;
      var emailReporter = issue.reporter.email;
      var emailWorker = issue.fields.Bearbeiter.email;
      var emailObserver = "";
      
      issue.fields.Beobachten.forEach(function(user) {
        emailObserver = emailObserver + user.email + ",";
      });   
      if(emailObserver.endsWith(",")) {
        emailObserver = emailObserver.substring(0,emailObserver.length-1);
      }  
      
      var message = {
        fromName: authorName,
        to: [emailReporter],
        cc: [emailWorker],
        bcc: [emailObserver],
        subject: 'New comment in ' + issue.id,
        headers: {
          'X-Custom-Header': 'Important value'
        },
        body: [
          '<div style="font-family: sans-serif">',
          '  <div style="padding: 10px 10px; font-size: 13px; border-bottom: 1px solid #D4D5D6;">',
          '    New comment was added in issue <a href=https://service-desk.dhge.de/tickets/'+issue.id+'>'+issue.id+'</a> by ' + authorName + ': ',
          '    <br> <br>' +   resolveLinks (issue.comments.last().text) ,
          '  </div>',
          '<\div>'
        ].join('\n')
      };

      console.log("Send mail from "+authorName+" to: "+emailReporter);
      console.log("Send mail from "+authorName+" to: "+emailWorker);
      console.log("Send mail from "+authorName+" to: "+emailObserver);
      console.log("Send mail text "+issue.comments.last().text);
      
      notification.sendEmail(message, issue);
    }
    
  }
});

How can I replace images with the correct ones?
I expected to see the attachments in the Email send by the comment-workflow. But only the markup syntax is in the Email - not the correct image or attachement. Line issue.comments.last().text should be resolved (wiki markup to HTML - with inline images or so).

Maybe this code helps?
function createGeneralMessage(issue) {
  const firstAddedComment = issue.comments.added.first();
  let text = firstAddedComment.text;
  const isMarkdown = firstAddedComment.isUsingMarkdown;
  issue.attachments.added.forEach(function (attachment) {
    if (isMarkdown) {
      text = text + '\n[' + attachment.name + '](' + attachment.fileUrl + ')';
    } else {
      text = text + '\n[file:' + attachment.name + ']';
    }
  });
  return issue.wikify(text, isMarkdown).trim();
}

